# If a field element is simultaneously an $m$th and $n$th power...

Tags: field-theory

Suppose $F$ is a field. Suppose we have $a,b \in F $ and relatively prime integers $m,n \geq 1$ such that $a^m = b^n$. Can I conclude that there is some $c \in F $ such that $c^{mn} = a^m = b^n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $xm+yn=1$ with $x,y$ integers.  Then $c=a^yb^x$ satisfies $c^{mn} = a^{ymn}b^{xmn} = (a^m)^{yn}(b^n)^{xm}=(b^n)^{yn+xm}=b^n$.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't one of $x$ or $y$ negative? I think you need group not monoid...

Comment: You're right, I misspoke. In that case we also need a tiny extra argument showing we can assume $a, b \neq 0$ WLOG, and so are invertible, and that does require knowing that $F$ is a field. Of course if $a = 0$ then $b = 0$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Bezout's identity says that there are integers $u,v$ such that
$$
um+vn=1.
$$
Divide that equation by $mn$.